# Python text file trim colon

Tags: python, string, text, trim, truncation

I've a text file that looks like this

```
firstname:lastname:123456789
somename:somelastname:12312456456
...
```

I want to put each name, lastname, and id into it's own variable.

This is how I made it so far.

```
with open("somefile.txt", 'r') as a:
    phonebook = a.readlines()

l = 0
while (len(phonebook) < l+1):
    firstname = 
    lastname =
    number =

    l++
```

And got stuck on the trimming part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just store the data in a list, a sublist for each line split into firat name, last name and id.

```
with open("somefile.txt", 'r') as f:
    data = [line.strip().split(":") for line in f]
```

You could also use a dict but there would be no real advantage unless you wanted to do lookups by name but even then names would need to be unique, if you just want to use each piece of data in a loop and not store all then use as your iterate:

```
with open("somefile.txt", 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
       fn, ln , _id = line.strip().split(":")
```

Comment: No prob, you're weclome.

Answer (score 1):

```
with open("somefile.txt", 'r') as a:
    for line in a:
        firstname, lastname, number = line.split(":")
        number = int(number)
```

There is no need to store the phonebook as a list in memory with `.readlines()`. This would be a problem if the file was big as you would use lots of memory. You can just iterate through it directly line by line. Extracting the variables is very easy thanks to the `str.split` method and tuple unpacking, you can look these up.